# How to keep decreasing value in mongo until is 0

Tags: javascript, mongodb

```
singleObj = await Objects.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: req.body.id, }, { $inc: { 'total_obj': -1, 'total_stuff': 1 }, }, { new: true })
```

The user clicks a button and the value of 'total_obj' gets decreased by one. The value doesn't have to be less than 0.
I have tried to do this:

```
singleObj = await Objects.findByIdAndUpdate(
  { _id: req.body.id, "total_obj": { "$lt": 0 } },
  { "$set": { "total_obj": 0 } }
);
```

But this messes up every time I load the page and I have the values set to 0.
I also added on the definition on the schema:

```
total_obj: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    min: 0
},
```

Comment: You say it doesn't need to be lesser than 0, why then there's `"total_obj": { "$lt": 0 }`?
Or did you mean that it can't be less than 0?

Comment: @DGX37 that it can't be less than 0

Comment: You have to use `$gt` then or it will only work when it's lesser than (`$lt`) 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to fetch the `Objects` instance first and update the value only if `> 0`:

```
const singleObj = await Objects.findById(req.body.id)
if (!singleObj) // Error, obj not found
if (singleObj.total_obj > 0) {
    singleObj.total_obj = singleObj.total_obj-1
    await singleObj.save()
} else { 
    // `total_obj` is already zero 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you meant that you don't want your value to be lesser than 0.
You would need to use `$gt` operator and while you used `$inc` properly in the first `findByIdAndUpdate` you didn't use it in the second one.

Also, we are not looking only for id so we should use `findOneAndUpdate` instead.

```
singleObj = await Objects.findOneAndUpdate(
   { _id: req.body.id, "total_obj": { "$gt": 0 } },
   { $inc: { "total_obj": -1 } }
);
```

Comment: what if instead I had this ? singleObj = await Objects.findOneAndUpdate(
   { _id: req.body.id, "total_obj": { "$gt": 0 } },
   { $inc: { "total_obj": -1 , "total_stuff" 1} }
); Can I still do this?

Comment: there's a typo, there should be a semicolon `"total_stuff": 1` and it will make total_obj smaller by one and total_stuff bigger by one. If that's what you want to do it should work.

Look at [$inc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) docs to get more information with examples.